# coded ui : mouse hover fails on different machine

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have recorded a test, in which mouse hover over a link.
on the same machine(say m/c A), where i recorded the test, mouse hovers over the link correctly.
But when running the same test on different machine(say m/c B), mouse hovers fails.
Since link doesn't have ID associated with it. It takes the co-ordinates and inner text as search property.

Tried recording mouse hover in m/c B, mouse correctly hovers over the link.

How to make sure that same test will run in different m/cs?

Thanks,
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

Try This

When you record It records coordinates of the link in designer file

(Eg:Mouse.Hover(linkObj,(12,8))), After moving the recorded method to .cs file remove the coordinates and run the test.

Comment: Instead of using record and playback.. Add control to designer. cs and write your own script.. It might work